# Field or property cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

The following bean definition:

```
<bean id="client" factory-bean="builder"
    factory-method="withConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
        value="#{ ${domain} == 'prod' ? 
                Base.${domain}.${realm}.rpt : Base.${domain}.${realm}}" />
```

fails with the following error:

`org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed { org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'test' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'`

*${domain}* should evaluate to 'test'.
What is wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your property-placeholder result has to be wrapped to `literal`, if you are going to test it against another literal and don't use it as a property as you in the rest of your expression:

```
value="#{ '${domain}' == 'prod' ? 
            'Base.${domain}.${realm}.rpt' : 'Base.${domain}.${realm}'}"
```

I've accepted your edit. Thanks.

The property-placeholder works before SpEL, so, any property-placeholder result becomes some SpEL part and it really has to be valid one.

I understand the first part `'${domain}' == 'prod'`, when you really must have a literal for the PP result to compare it with another literal. The rest of your SpEL hasn't been clear for me from the beginning, but now I see that it should be a `String` too for ctor arg.

Otherwise SpEL tries to treat `test` as some evaluation context property, that we see in the exception.

Try to imagine your SpEL without property-placeholders.

Comment: Sorry could not understand what you meant by : "and don't use it as a property as you in the rest of your expression". I want this functionality: `if domain has value "prod", then use "Base.prod.US.rpt" as constructor argument otherwise use "Base.test.US" as argument`. Note that `${realm}` evaluates to US.

Comment: I have edited the answer to be completely correct. jsut that I did not understand that particular portion.

Answer (score 2):

Because I did not add in the missing apostrophes:

```
th:if = "${user.name} == null";
```

The correct way is:

```
th:if = "'${user.name}' == null";
```

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment to an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

For boolean field use '' like below

```
${'offer.isActive'}
```